# Do I need the forward slash after height="1" on the tracking pixel? -

Tags: html

When I add a tracking pixel to a banner do I need the forward slash at the end of the pixel img tag?

```html
<a href="//cyberpowerpc.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://x.com/CyberPowerPC/1571/6114.jpg" alt=""><img src="https://my.x.net/img.gif?f=sync&lr=1&partner=4082bf34c3f1bd060df7166ac0fabf7ee7e5d7686a1213b35cc55b6f61b00b71" width="1" height="1" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need it... that syntax is deprecated.

Comment: I'll make the edit. With comments like that it is always ok to make the edit yourself and then flag the comment as no longer needed as the comment refers to something that has been fixed.